# UIImageView Crossfade Animation Manual Progress

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an image view I want to have crossfading between two images. There isn't a set time I want this animation to take place, however. I want it to be controlled by a slider where they can slide between viewing the two images and having them crossfade relative to the slider's progress.

My question is, is there a better way to do this than overlaying two UIImageViews and adjusting the alpha property for the top one? Is there a way I can manually set a crossfade animation's progress between two images using one UIImageView?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not the best of coders out there, but I would probably take the alpha approach.  Is there a reason why you don't want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iCarousel which will let you do crossfade animations within a single view. 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

iCarousel is a class designed to simplify the implementation of various types of carousel (paged, scrolling views)